# Lebsgue Integral with respect to probability measure

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral

Im trying to find the Integral over the real Numbers of a constant Number (j-i) with respect to a probability measure P. Im new to lebesgue Integration and would appreciate any help :).

Comment: Integral of a constant $c$ w.r.t. a probability measure is $c$.

Comment: so that means in conclusion that the lebsegue Integral of one w.r.t. P is still 1. am i right ?

Comment: Have you read the definition of integral of a simple function with respect to a measure?

Comment: i tried but i have troubles applying this to a constant function. Im not sure how i can describe the constant function as a Sum that includes the indicator function.

Comment: What is the indicator function of the whole space?

Comment: it should be 1 ?

Comment: is it possible to write my function as the product of 1 and the indicator function over the real Numbers (to get the form as a simple function)? then i can say that the probability P(R) is equal to one? and in conclusion my integral should be still the constant ?